# Updating DatagridView with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagridview

I would like to update my mySQL table from a DatagridView with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns and display it back to my forms. However, my current code checks all rows even if only a single CheckBoxColumn has been checked. Checked or unchecked rows should be both updated so I'm not sure if I still have to add condition if DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns are checked.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridFamMedHistory.Rows)          
{                
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    famMedHistorytype = datagridFamMedHistory.Rows[0].Cells["colType"].Value.ToString();
    command.CommandText = @"UPDATE familymedhistory SET paternal = @paternal, maternal = @maternal
                                    WHERE patientid = '" + patientid + "' AND type = '" + famMedHistorytype + "'";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paternal", row.Cells["colPaternal"].Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maternal", row.Cells["colMaternal"].Value);
    connect.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
}
```

I think I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figured it out.

[image: visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve and current output.]

Comment: Opening and closing a database connection *for each row* as well as running the update script *for each row* is **very** inefficient. Consider redesigning your approach.

Comment: this is well noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you debugged your code?

You are still selecting row 0 in your loop

change :

```
  famMedHistorytype = datagridFamMedHistory.Rows[0].Cells["colType"].Value.ToString();
```

to :

```
  famMedHistorytype = row.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
```

Also As collegue wrote in comment, do not open and close connection in loop.. my eyes are bleeding

Comment: Thank you for this and I loved to hear these types of added advice as best practices.